# The Mix manifest does not exist. Not appear folder and files in the `public` folder

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-mix

I downloaded the laravel(8.75) project from git and am trying to run it on a local server

I made:

```
npm install
npm install laravel-mix@latest
npm ci
npm run dev
```

The js, css folders and json should appear in the `public` folder, but this does not happen.
Node v14.15.5, laravel-mix v6.0.49

npm run dev output

```
> @ dev c:\OpenServer\domains\cons.loc
> npm run development


> @ development c:\OpenServer\domains\cons.loc
> mix
```

No recommendations of answers from other similar questions help. What could be the matter?

Comment: you do not need to run `npm install laravel-mix@latest`, you just need to run `npm install`, and `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`. What is the output of `npm run dev` and what is `npm ci`?

Comment: @matiaslauriti

npm ci
npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation

> vue-demi@0.13.1 postinstall c:\OpenServer\domains\cons.loc\node_modules\pinia\node_modules\vue-demi
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js

added 852 packages in 115.798s

 ||||||||||| npm run dev

> @ dev c:\OpenServer\domains\cons.loc
> npm run development


> @ development c:\OpenServer\domains\cons.loc
> mix

Comment: The mix-manifest.json file is generated aftart you run nmp run prod npm run watch commands

Comment: @user43436 I am sorry, I have no idea what you have posted. You have to edit your question and add the output there as text. Explain what is `npm ci` as it does not exist by default on Laravel. What did you install? Same for `npm run dev` output

Comment: @matiaslauriti done. I get warning "Missing Mix Manifest File
Did you forget to run npm ci && npm run dev?" - so i make npm ci and npm  run dev as well

Comment: @B A no, no works both

Comment: @user43436 you will need to add more info, I literally run the following commands in that exact order: `composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example-app`, `cd example-app`, `npm install`, `npm install laravel-mix@latest`, `npm ci`, `npm run dev` and it worked without any issues... I think you have an issue because you are using Windows, but if you have no errors on the output, I have no idea then. In my case, I am using WSL2 -> Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @matiaslauriti @B A thank you very much for your try to help. I understood that issue   with the project  from git. The built works on a clean project

Comment: @user43436 correct, it works on a clean new project with the same version